# Java Spring JDBCtemplate take time for first request

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, jdbctemplate, java-stored-procedures

I am using Java and Spring Jdbctemplate to hit a stored procedure and fetch the data. This is deployed as war to Weblogic server. Problem I face is the first request is much slower (10 secs) or it takes more time. But the consequent request is faster (2 secs).

How can I make the first request also faster like consequent requests. I did research and thought of implementing cache like ehcache but even after implementing it I feel first requests will take same amount of time.

Below is the code I am using:

```
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {     
    final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();               
    DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("DATA_SOURCE");  //DATASOURCE configured in weblogic
    return dataSource;
 } 

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
    jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(getDataSource());        
    return jdbcTemplate;
}
....
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(getJdbcTemplate()) 
                    .withSchemaName("")
                    .withCatalogName("")
                    .withProcedureName("");
jdbcCall.execute(sqlInParam);
```

What can I try?

Comment: How you estimated this?  Such delay could be due to initial application load, which is delayed till first call to application's context.

Comment: I had loggers in different places and calculated based on it.

Comment: Well, there is connection pool behind JdbcTemplate, this pool maintains multiple opened connections to database. There could be incorrect configuration of pool,  like min/max opened connections, too short connection timeout, incorrect validation string and so on. All these could produce  delays you seen.

Comment: I really hope that `getJdbcTemplate` isn't called like that. But rather on an injected `JdbcTemplate`. Could you please add the actual code you are using, as these seem like snippets (which should be in different classes).